# What is $\alpha$ in SVM Lagrangian fucntions

Tags: svm, lagrange-multipliers

Is it a column matrix or a row matrix? I saw on a CMU slide that $\alpha$ is defined as $\alpha=(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_n)^T>=0$? I dont see much of a formal definition for the exact form of $\alpha$ in the SVM Lagrangian functions, given that the data X is usually a matrix.

PS: here is the link for that slide [http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aarti/Class/10701_Spring14/slides/SupportVectorMachines.pdf](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eaarti/Class/10701_Spring14/slides/SupportVectorMachines.pdf)

Comment: It may depend on the notation that the authors choose to use in order to make their derivations more convenient. But the most common way of writing a vector (like $\alpha$) is to write it as a column matrix.